# .Val() set value, but not show into TextBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

So, i have a problem with a function un JS, how call a Ajax request :

```js
function editDataAddress(idPartnerAddress) {
        // simplified
        var url = "@Url.Action("SelectAddressToEdit", "Partners", idPartnerAddress)"
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var adresse = data.Address;
                var zip = data.Zip;
                var locality = data.Locality;
                var idLocalite = data.IdLocality;

                //alert("locality : "+locality);

                $("#ZipSwiss").empty()
                $("#ZipSwiss").append($('<option></option>').val(idLocalite).html(zip));

                
                $('#PartnerAdresse_Locality').val(locality)
              // This line confirm i don't have another PartnerAdresse_Locality in my page
                console.log('ID Test:', $('[id=PartnerAdresse_Locality]').length, $('[id=PartnerAdresse_Locality]').get())

            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4" id="divZipSwiss">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ZipSwiss, ViewBag.localiteList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Recherche...", new {@class = "form-control", style = "width : 100%;"})
</div>
  
<div class="col-md-5">
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PartnerAdresse.Locality, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

The problem is, when i call the function, the ajax return all value, and put in the 4 first var (adresse, zip, locality, idlocalite) correctly

When i do the `$('#PartnerAdresse_Locality').val(locality)`, the value is set in the HTML, but not show : [image: Picture of result]
and the HTML :

```
<input class="form-control" id="PartnerAdresse_Locality" name="PartnerAdresse.Locality" type="text" value="Geneva">
```

The NPA (Zip) is okay, and the locality value is filled, but not showing

**if now I comment** `$("#ZipSwiss").append($('<option</option>').val(idLocalite).html(zip));`
the locality appears, but of course, no more the NPA (zip) because of the comment.

i'm really lost, somebody can help me?

Comment: You are missing a closing tag > after option in your append. Is this a typo in your code or only in your question?

Comment: Thanks, I edited. It was a error of copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

Following my explanation, i founded the solution by comment some code line :

for my ZipSwiss, I Have a select2 DDL :

```
$('#ZipSwiss')
            .select2({
                language: lang,
                minimumInputLength: 2,
                minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
                closeOnSelect: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("SearchLocalite", "Partners")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 200,
                    data: function(params) {
                        return {
                            searchTerm: params.term
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function(data) {
                        return {
                            results: $.map(data, function(item) {
                                return {
                                    id: item.IdLocalite,
                                    text: item.ZipCode,
                                    name: item.Name
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    },
                    cache: true
                },
                templateResult: function(item) {
                    if (item.loading)
                        return item.text;

                    return item.text + " | " + item.name;
                },
                templateSelection: function (item) {
                    $("#PartnerAdresse_Locality").val(item.name);
                    return item.text;
                },
                escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
                     return markup;
                }
            });
```

The line : `$("#PartnerAdresse_Locality").val(item.name);` is called ALWAYS when you update the selection. it's mean, the value is null.

Thanks ^^